# Alignment of Wide east asian characters with format function

Tags: python, unicode

I am using python `format` method to align [East Asian Wide (EAW) characters](http://unicode.org/reports/tr11/) in my terminal display. The following python3 code illustrates my problem.

```
ZH_STRING1 = "東京大学"
ZH_STRING2 = "麻将"

print(">" + "01234567" + "<")
print(">" + format(ZH_STRING1, ">4") + "<")
print(">" + format(ZH_STRING2, ">4") + "<")
print("---")
print("Length:         ", len(ZH_STRING2))
```

The terminal output (see image below) shows that EAW character width is twice the width of an ordinary character, while the `len` function return the correct number of characters (one for each ideograph).

[image: Terminal output of bad east asian wide characters aligment.]

The python `format` function evaluate `ZH_STRING1` length as 4 and `ZH_STRING2` length as 2, and the `format` function adds two space characters to make the alignment. Unfortunately, the different width between EAW and space characters messes the terminal output.

So, how can I het the correct aligment?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I found a solution while writing this question. ^^

It is quite simple: Use the Unicode Ideographic Space (U+3000) in the python `format` function, which takes to normal spaces on the terminal output:

```
ZH_STRING1 = "東京大学"
ZH_STRING2 = "麻将"

print(">" + "01234567" + "<")
print(">" + format(ZH_STRING1, "　>4") + "<")
print(">" + format(ZH_STRING2, "　>4") + "<")
```

Then:

[image]